# Array displays correctly inside a loop, but once outside the array seems to lose all information

Tags: arrays, file-io, while-loop

Im a noob at this and was wondering why my array will output correctly within the while loop but once i cout the array outside of the while loop no information is displayed?
if you can explain it in beginner terms id really appreciate it.

```
   void Video::Read_Video()
{
    ifstream Din;
Din.open("Video.txt");
    if(!Din)
            cerr << "Could not open video.txt for reading." << endl;
    else
    {
        for(int i=0; i < Num_Of_Videos; i++)
        {
            while(Din.good())
            {
                getline(Din, Video_Array[i]);
                Num_Of_Videos++;
                cout << "Set_Video says these are the movies" << Video_Array[i] << endl;
            }
                                cout << "Set_Video says these are the movies" << Video_Array[i] << endl;

        }
        Num_Of_Videos = Num_Of_Videos-2;


    }
Din.close();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop don't make any sense. Inside the `for` loop, `i` is not incremented. So you keep reading into the same element of `Video_Array`. It's not clear exactly what it is you're trying to do, but the code as written doesn't make much sense. Why do you have two loops?

Comment: the i will increase by one with every successful loop because of the "i++" i have five lines in a text file that i am trying to read in one line at a time into five different members of my string array"Video_Array[]". The first loop is to assign the lines in the text file to 5 different members in the array. and the second is to count the number of lines in the text file for the for loop.

Comment: The `i` will increase by one with every successful loop of the **for** loop. But your read occurs inside the **while** loop. Nothing inside the *while* loop increments `i`. I still don't understand why you have two loops.

Comment: ok i just got what you were referring to. That fixed it. thanks alot man